# Are "reckless" and "feckless" synonyms?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

Both *reckless* and *feckless* imply not taking responsibility. When is it appropriate to use the one over the other?

Comment: Are reck and feck synonyms?

Comment: This isn't quite general reference. It's about two similar-sounding words with somewhat similar meanings with a fine shade of difference (covered in some of our answers). It's worth articulating those (fine) differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They can be synonyms, but [note](http://thesaurus.com/browse/feckless):

> **feckless** means ineffective or having no real worth or purpose; **reckless** means marked by unthinking boldness or with defiant disregard for danger or consequences

It may help to remember their etymologies:

- Easy to remember: *[feck](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=feckless&allowed_in_frame=0)* from the Scottish shortened form of *effect*.
- Hard to remember: *[reck](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=reckless&allowed_in_frame=0)* from the Old High German *to have regard*.

Comment: `reck` as in `reckon`? doesn't seem so hard to remember...

Comment: @Karl: *Reck* and *reckon* have different etymological roots, different modern meanings.

Comment: @Hugo: I have voted to reopen-- see my comment with regard to the question. I have upvoted your answer because I felt it addressed the question, and am inviting you to join me in voting to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

With regard to "responsibility," fecklessness is a sin of OMISSION, while recklessness is a sin of COMMISSION.

That is "feckless" means not TAKING responsibility, while reckless means being IRresponsible.

Comment: I like the rampant capitalization.